# How change position of "Logout" and menu for "shinymanager" R package?

Tags: r, shiny

I use "shinymanager" to auth users for R Shiny dashboard. By default, the position of the menu with "Logout" button is the  "right bottom" corner.

```
ui <- secure_app(UI)
```

Any ideas on how to change position on let say "right top" corner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a parameter to set in the secure_app function called fab_position:

```
ui <- secure_app(UI,
                 fab_position = "top-right")
```